# Symfony3 with checkboxes retrieved from database tables

Tags: php, database, checkbox, symfony

I'm trying to get a good Symfony3 solution for a Form containing checkboxes. The total number of checkboxes are retrieved from one table (the CategoryList table) and in another table I've stored which Categories for a certain domain are selected.

```
Table: Domain
ID     DomainName
1      TestDomain1
2      TestDomain2
3      TestDomain3

Table: CategoryList
ID     CategoryName
1      Unknown
2      Cat-1
3      Cat-2

Table: DomainCategory
ID     Domain_ID     DomainCategoryList_ID
1      1             1
2      1             2
3      1             3
4      2             2
5      3             1
```

The DomainCategory table contains the relationship between the Domains and the categories to which the Domains belong to.

Domains --> DomainCategory <--> CategoryList

How can I create a Symfony3 form for this?

I tried to use the EntityType::class and passing the CategoryList object to it, then I get indeed all the Categories as checkboxes but I cannot specify which checkbox needs to be checked/ticked depending on the DomainCategory table.

Any suggestions on how to solve this? Or any good reference to an example implementation. I was not able to find it after spending a week solving this problem.

Comment: Could be a good point, please tell me/explain to me how it should work this abstraction layer. The ManyToOne tables/Doctrine abstraction layer is working perfectly. The topic this is about is a two times a ManyToMany relationship. Domains <-> DomainCategory <-> CategoryList. If you have a good example how to solve this it would be appreciated but I was not able to find it.

Comment: With Symfony/Doctrine I can link the Domain table with the DomainCategory table but then only the records in that table will be shown on the form. I need to have all possible items from the DomainCategoryList to be shown on the form and the ones listed in DomainCategory for the specific Domain needs to be checked. How to solve this problem in Symfony 3 / Doctrine? Any suggestion......